# How to solve the dependency error in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, macos, dependencies

[image: screen shoot]

I download a new project from the Internet. When i try to run it, this error shows up which says there is no such dependency in my macbook. how to solve this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point of posting a picture that others can barely see without a magnifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You should first deintegrate the podfile
2.Install the pod file.
3.Clean the project and run the code.

Hope it will helps.